# Syntax error trying to set up invalid character array

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, syntax-error

I'm fairly new to PHP, and I'm setting up a "members area" for my site following [this tutorial](http://www.allsyntax.com/tutorials/PHP/26/Complete-Members-System/4.php).  There seems to be a problem with the code near the bottom of the page.

When trying to pick out the invalid characters from a username field, the array $junk is set up.

```
$junk = array('.' , ',' , '/' , '\' , '`' , ';' , '[' ,  ']' , '-', '_', '*', '&', '^',
'%', '$', '#', '@', '!', '~', '+', '(', ')', '|', '{', '}', '<', '>', '?', ':', '"', '=');
```

This block of code returns a syntax error for me.

Now, my first thought was that either the '#' or the '(' and ')' was causing the problem, since they are commonly used in html and php.  The error was still returned with them removed.

I am new to php, so it very well could be just some small syntax error I am missing.  Any input would be great.  Thanks!

EDIT: Also, if there is an easier way of doing this, please let me know!

Comment: Depending on which characters you want to kick out, a regular expression could be simpler. (Also, why do you need to remove these characters from usernames? I can't think of any non-artificial reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do this, regular expressions. 
If you want to set up the username to only accept alpha-numeric characters it's,

$user = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z]+/", "", $user);

The expression essentially says, replace anything that is not 0-9, a-z, A-Z with "". If you want to allow the "@", "." (period) and "-" and "_" symbols:

```
$user = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z\@\.\-\_]+/", "", $user);
```

Regular expressions are a very powerful tool. They can be used in most languages, including javascript and PHP. So it is worth taking the time to learn them.

Answer (score 1):

For '\' character you need to write it like

```
'\\'
```

Answer (score 1):

The backslash needs to be escaped: `'\\'`. That's because `\'` gives you a literal apostrophe, which you couldn't otherwise get inside a singly quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

for a smaller array, make a string and then call str_split to get it as an array of chars.

```
$junk = str_split('.,/\\`;[]-_*&^%S#@!~+()|{}<>?:"=')
```

Personally I would have used the chars in the following order

```
~`!@#$%^&*()-_+={}[]\|;:'",.<>/?
```

Since that is how they are on my keyboard.  But that's just a minor issue.  I knows the ' (single quote) is missing from the original string.

Better ways to validate input involve regular expressions.